# STUSB4500: Usecase for 50mV fine adjustment?

Tags: power-supply, usb-c

To power a scanner, I need 7.2V at 1.5A.

So I got STM's [EVAL-SCS001V1](https://www.st.com/en/product/EVAL-SCS001V1) breakout board built around the STUSB4500 USB PD sink controller. In the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stusb4500.pdf#page=19&zoom=100,0,145) it says about the two configurable PDO profiles:

> Flexible voltage value
> 5 V ≤ 0.05*V_SNK_PDO2_FLEX[9:0] ≤ 20 V by steps of 50 mV

Cool, but according to USB Power Delivery [specification](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-power-delivery) revision 2.0, the only voltages supported are: +5 V, +9 V, +15 V, +20 V

*With USB PD having only a few voltages to choose from, what's the usecase for the fine adjustment in 50 mV steps?*

About my application: I have now programmed the STUSB4500 to output 9V or 15V, and then I drop the voltage to 7.2V using a LM2596 buck converter.

Comment: Where is the link to this: `USB Power Delivery specification revision 2.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine voltage and current steps are used by the USB Programmable Power Supply (PPS) spec:

> The PPS standard allows the USB C power source to provide voltage and current control for direct battery charging and to reduce the power losses. The nominal step sizes for a PPS power source are 20mV for output voltage and 50mA for current limiting. The voltage range includes a 3.3V minimum and a 21V maximum.

https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/usb-type-c-boost-and-buck-boost-solution-for-pps

This is primarily used on mobile devices that support fast charging in order to run their internal switching regulators at maximum efficiency in order to maximize charge current while minimizing heat.

Comment: Glad I asked. I may look into getting a PPS charger now for the application, instead of using the LM2596.

Comment: I now did some test with a PPS charger, only to realize that the STUSB4500, according to its [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stusb4500.pdf), only supports USB PD rev 2.0, while PPS is an optional feature of PD 3.